# How to enable multimedia keys?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, mate, multimedia

I've installed `ubuntu mate 15.04` last night and I've just noticed that multimedia keys (play ,next ,pause ...) of my AOpen KB932 standard keyboard are not working.

I'm confused because it was working fine in my old `ubuntu 14.04` and the two versions are supposed to have the same driver.

`xev` output when I press the play key:

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 35, synthetic NO , window 0x0
Keys: 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Is there any way to make those keys work back ? otherwise how to configure other keys so that they function as multimedia keys ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Open a terminal and start `sudo showkey`. Use the multimedia keys. Is there an output?

Comment: No nothing happens when I press them.

Comment: Try it with `xev`

Comment: This is what I get, seems like the system is detecting the keys ..
`KeymapNotify event, serial 35, synthetic NO , window 0x0`

Comment: Something is still missing, the next rows.

Comment: Sorry 
The whole output is
`KeymapNotify event, serial 35, synthetic NO , window 0x0

Keys: 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

          0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a strange solution to make the keys works if someone is getting the same issue i hope this helps.
It's not the best solution for sure because you have to do it everytime Ubuntu starts but at least you can use multimedia keys when needed.

Unplug the keyboard when starting the system (after Grub menu) and plug it back before the login menu.